# Visual Studio 2022 crashes and restarts when comparing views from 2 local branches

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am not sure if this is for here or not but, I am comparing files between 2 different local branches in visual studio 2022, and everything goes fine with js files but once I start comparing views then VS crashes and restarts on me every time.

Has anyone encountered this issue or maybe an idea on why VS would do this or how to fix the problem?